# Bash script to temporarily run a shell without certain group memberships

Tags: security, bash, linux, unix, authorization

I have here a script called `rwog` (**r**un **w**ith**o**ut **g**roups) that allow a user to run a shell without particular group memberships.  `rwog`, in more detail...

- Is primarily for a support staffer to pretend to be an ordinary user without  `su`-ing to anybody.
- Must be run as `root`, but those allowed to run it will be given an entry in `/etc/sudoers`.
- Should be executed as `sudo rwog groups to drop`.
- Will have a `uid` of `root`, a `gid` of `the_support_team`, and permissions `0550` (i.e. user and group can read and execute, world can do nothing, and no `setgid`/`setuid` bits).
- Cannot change your `gid`, change your `uid`, or add yourself to supplementary groups.
- Revokes pretty much all [capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html), though this may be a tad zealous.
- Does not modify `/etc/group` (so `id` will be changed, but `id $USER` will not).
- Is primarily (but not exclusively) intended to run on a Centos 7 environment..

My main concern: **Can this script be exploited to gain escalated privileges?** 
 I won't ignore suggestions not related to security.

## The Script

```
#!/bin/bash

function help(){
    echo "rwog - run without groups";
    echo "Runs a shell as if you weren't in certain supplementary groups."
    echo "Good for pretending that you're not a support user."
    echo "Usage example:";
    echo -e "\trwog [(-h|--help)] [group ...]";
    echo "Options:";
    echo -e "\t-h or --help: Displays this information.";
    exit 1;
}

# Declare vars. Flags initalizing to 0.

# Execute getopt
ARGS=$(getopt -o "h" -l "help" -n "rwog" -- "$@");

#Bad arguments
if [ $? -ne 0 ];
then
    help;
fi

eval set -- "$ARGS";

while true; do
    case "$1" in
        -h|--help)
            shift;
            help;
            ;;

        --)
            shift;
            break;
            ;;
    esac
done


if [[ $(id -u) != 0 ]]; then
    # If you're not root...
    echo "You must be root to use this script. Run it with sudo."
    exit 1
fi

for group in $@; do
    # For each group we want to drop...

    if [[ "$group" == "$SUDO_USER" ]]; then
        # If you're trying to drop your own gid...
        echo "You cannot drop your own gid."
        exit 1
    elif ! getent group "$group" &>/dev/null ; then
        #If this group doesn't exist...
        echo "$group is not a valid group."
        exit 1
    elif  ! groups "$SUDO_USER" | grep -E &>/dev/null "\b$group\b"; then
        # Else if you're not actually a member of this group...
        echo "Not a member of $group, cannot drop it"
        exit 1
    fi
done

my_groups=$(id -Gn "$SUDO_USER" | xargs -n1 | sort -u)
groups_to_drop=$(echo $@ | xargs -n1 | sort -u)
# Put the groups that you want to drop on multiple lines, then sort them

if [[ -z "$groups_to_drop" ]]; then
    # If you didn't pick a group to drop...
    echo "Please specify at least one supplementary group to drop."
    help
fi

reduced_groups=$(comm -13 <(echo "$groups_to_drop") <(echo "$my_groups") | paste -s -d,)
# Subtract the groups we want to drop from the groups we're in, then merge them onto one line

export USERNAME="$SUDO_USER"
export USER="$SUDO_USER"
export LOGNAME="$SUDO_USER"
export HOME=$( getent passwd "$SUDO_USER" | cut -d: -f6 )

dropped_capabilities=$(capsh --print | grep -E "Bounding set =(.+)" | sed "s/Bounding set =//g")

capsh --secbits=0xf --drop="$dropped_capabilities" --groups="$reduced_groups" --gid="$SUDO_GID" --uid="$SUDO_UID" -- --login
```

Comment: I was surprised to find that this script is necessary, and that `sg` and `newgrp` don't already have support for changing supplementary groups.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## It's not an error to ask for help

When `-h` is passed, the `help()` function shouldn't exit with non-zero status, because it's done what was asked for.

Conversely, when we pass no arguments, we should exit with non-zero, and we should write the message to the standard error stream.

I'd write that as

```
help() {
    local tab=$'\t'
    cat <<END
$0 - run without groups
Runs a shell as if you weren't in certain supplementary groups.
Good for pretending that you're not a support user.
Usage example:
${tab}$0 [(-h|--help)] [group ...]
Options:
${tab}-h or --help: Displays this information.
END
}
```

And then use it as

```
# Just use the command directly instead of testing $?
if ! ARGS=$(getopt -o "h" -l "help" -n "rwog" -- "$@");
then
    help >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

and

```
    case "$1" in
        -h|--help)
            help
            exit 0
            ;;
```

Elsewhere in the code, diagnostic messages are printed to standard output; these should all be redirected to `&2`.

## Checking more exit statuses

We depend on tools such as `xargs` and `sort` that might not be present.  Consider letting Bash check some statuses, but make sure you know which commands this will not check:

```
set -e
```

Also consider getting Bash to check that you're not using unset variables:

```
set -u
```

You'll want to use expansions such as `${foo:-}` when you need to avoid this checking.

## Quote your variable expansions

Just because you've checked that this is being run by root (perhaps overkill - is it sufficient to be any user that can run `capsh`?), doesn't mean that they can't do something unexpected.  So write `"$@"`, not `$@`:

```
for group in "$@"; do
```

## Don't compare a group against a user

```
if [[ "$group" == "$SUDO_USER" ]]; then
```

Did you mean `"$SUDO_GID"` there?  Also, there's little point using both `[[`...`]]` and quotes - I'd stick to the portable `[`...`]` here.

If you did mean to compare against the user name (e.g. you know your configuration always creates a per-user group sharing the same name), then it's a good idea to add a comment documenting that assumption, as it might not be valid on another system you copy this to.

## No need to `grep` and `sed` in a pipeline

Sed is perfectly capable of selecting lines:

```
dropped_capabilities=$(capsh --print | sed -n -e 's/Bounding set =//gp')
```

## Take care with `$PATH`

Even though your site's `sudo` policy should constrain `PATH`, it may be a good idea to set a specific `PATH` at the start of the script and/or use fully-qualified pathnames for executables.

Comment: Actually, I did mean to compare `$group` with `$SUDO_USER`, because most Linux systems put users in a singleton group that shares their name and ID number.

Comment: In that case, it's probably worth documenting the assumption in a comment - I'll add a note to the review.

Comment: So which of these are potential security risks?  `$PATH` and variable expansions I understand.  Anything else?

Comment: Failing to check whether commands exist *may* fall into that category, though I don't see immediately how to exploit it.  There's certainly a problem if users are able to modify any directories in the search path ahead of the intended executables.  I'd recommend specifying all programs using absolute paths.

Comment: ...wait, I just had a thought.  What if someone pipes the script through `sed` to replace parts of the script in a way that grants them root access, then pipes that to `bash`?  Isn't that a problem?

Comment: Only if they can overwrite the program or they can somehow otherwise persuade `sudo` to run it for them, in which case all bets were off to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Some minor points on top of Toby's excellent review.

#### Input validation

This check should be moved higher up in the code:

> ```
> if [[ -z "$groups_to_drop" ]]; then
>     # If you didn't pick a group to drop...
>     echo "Please specify at least one supplementary group to drop."
>     help
> fi
> ```

This happens after `for group in $@`, after `my_groups` is created, and after `groups_to_drop` is created from `$@`. The check on whether `$@` is empty should come before all those operations.

A tip: instead of `for group in "$@"; do`, you could write `for group; do` to the same effect.

#### Style

In the first half of the script,
many lines end with a redundant `;`. Remove those.